# How To Change Encrypted Passwords In PHPMyAdmin Control Panel?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, password-encryption

I'm creating database tables for store user data so I have to encrypt password field in database table is there any method to encrypt on the control panel ?

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `password_hash`/`password_verify`, `PBKDF2` (aka `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`), `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: zaph has good advice about passwords; you should not store a password in a reversible means. Use a hash instead. You also mention "user data" so I figured you also mean private information that needs to be reversible such as social security number or credit card information; something that should not be stored at rest in plaintext. For more about hashes, there are many good questions in the Related section to the right.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, phpMyAdmin allows you to easily use all of the MySQL functions, including `AES_ENCRYPT`, `ENCRYPT`, `SHA1`, and so on. On the Insert tab, there's a dropdown to select the MySQL function you wish to use.

[image: Insert function dropdown]

Comment: Encrypting passwords is not secure and puts the users at risk, please do not do that. See the comment to the question.

Comment: True, but the same dropdown allows you to select hash functions as well. Just because I happened to stop on AES_ENCRYPT instead of one of the built-in hash functions doesn't really change the answer. MySQL doesn't natively support some of the more popular hash functions and as a result, you can't invoke them natively from within MySQL (or phpMyAdmin) and would have to get the hash result before performing the insert.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. See the comment to the question. PHP Admin and DBs are slow to catch-up with best practices so the security of passwords needs to be done outside of PHP Admin/MySQL. Aside, ya' gotta love the '80s retro ALL CAPS!

Comment: This is PHP Admin, one would think supporting PHP `password_hash` and `password_vertify` would go together like peanut butter and jelly.